# Stack allocator access violation when enabling MSVC debug iterator

Tags: c++, visual-c++, allocator

I've made a simple stack allocator that can be used to allocate small containers on the stack.
I've been using this class for a while and it has been working fine.
However, today I switched debug iterators back on (`_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=2`), and I am suddenly getting access violations in the debugging code that was activated by this switch.

The mix of template programming and standard library coding conventions is making this very hard to debug, and I'm not exactly an expert on allocators either. Am I violating some sort of rule for allocators?

The code below should be able to reproduce the error.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

template <typename T, size_t N, template <typename> typename Allocator = std::allocator>
class StackAllocator : public Allocator<T>
{
    public:
    using base         = Allocator<T>;
    using pointer_type = typename base::pointer;
    using size_type    = typename base::size_type;

    StackAllocator() noexcept = default;
    StackAllocator(const StackAllocator& a_StackAllocator) noexcept = default;

    template <typename U>
    StackAllocator(const StackAllocator<U, N, Allocator>& a_StackAllocator) noexcept
    {
    }

    pointer_type allocate(size_type a_Size, void* a_Hint = nullptr)
    {
        if (!m_Active && a_Size <= N)
        {
            m_Active = true;
            return GetStackPointer();
        }
        else
        {
            return base::allocate(a_Size, a_Hint);
        }
    }

    void deallocate(pointer_type a_Pointer, size_type a_Size)
    {
        if (a_Pointer == GetStackPointer())
        {
            m_Active = false;
        }
        else
        {
            base::deallocate(a_Pointer, a_Size);
        }
    }

    template <class U>
    struct rebind
    {
        using other = StackAllocator<U, N, Allocator>;
    };

    private:
    pointer_type GetStackPointer()
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<pointer_type>(m_Data);
    }

    std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)> m_Data[N];
    bool m_Active = false;
};

template <typename T, size_t N>
class StackVector : public std::vector<T, StackAllocator<T, N>>
{
    public:
    using allocator_type = StackAllocator<T, N>;
    using base           = std::vector<T, allocator_type>;

    StackVector() noexcept(noexcept(allocator_type())):
        StackVector(allocator_type())
    {
    }

    explicit StackVector(const allocator_type& a_Allocator) noexcept(noexcept(base(a_Allocator))):
        base(a_Allocator)
    {
        base::reserve(N);
    }

    using base::vector;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    StackVector<size_t, 1> v;

    return v.capacity();
}
```

I am using MSVC 2017 (15.4.0).

Comment: The standard requires that an allocator `b` copy-constructed from allocator `a` be equal to `a`; which in turn means that memory allocated by `a` can be deallocated by `b`. Your class violates this requirement, and is therefore not a valid allocator. In fact, you inherit `std::allocator::operator==` which always returns `true`; but instances of your class are very much not interchangeable.

Comment: Original answer got downvoted, but the main point is you cannot have the storage be in the allocator because these are stateless value-like types. I don't even see how you would support multiple such allocators with the same type. Plus you have to take pains to guarantee the storage doesn't go out of scope while the allocation is still in use. E.g. asserting deallocate is called before destruction of the storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed the violation of the requirement that @Igor stated. I've fixed this issue by storing the stack data outside of the allocator. Now the StackVector is the owner of the data, and the allocator and its copies all point to that memory, ensuring that memory allocated by one allocator can be deallocated by a copy of that allocator.

This solution does force a bit of complexity on the user (now has to manage 2 objects instead of 1), but there seems to be no other way while staying within the allocator requirements, and it can be avoided by wrapping the container as well.

A great example of this solution can be found in [Chromium's StackAllocator](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/chromium/+/master/base/stack_container.h).